# How to read an int from the console in a beginner-friendly way?

Tags: java

I'm helping someone learn Java at the moment. I'm a senior C# developer. I understand programming in general but I do not know the Java APIs.

Most advice on the web on how to read an int from the console is complicated. It involves `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` and such. This is completely incomprehensible to a beginner.

I want to provide him with a function `static int readIntFromConsole()` that does this. What would the body of that function be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Now using the readIntFromConsole()

        int myNumber = readIntFromConsole();
        System.out.println(myNumber);
    }

    public static int readIntFromConsole() {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer value....");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = s.nextInt();
        return number;
    }

}
```

//Edit: provided the required method

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter some integer:\t");

int myIntValue = scanner.nextInt();
```

In order to use through the lifespan of your test application, you can do the following:

```
public void scanInput() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter some integer:\t");
        int myIntValue = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("You entered:\t" + myInteValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to instantiate a new Scanner for each invocation? I could tell him to use this: `new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()`.

Comment: The proper way is to instantiate the Scanner class once and then use it throughout the life cycle of your application. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @boot4life you don't need to instantiate a new Scanner everytime. Just get one instance and it works well everytime.

Comment: I want to avoid any variables. This is for a beginner. Is it safe to instantiate a Scanner all the time?

Comment: It is safe, but, if you want to show it to a beginner, you should use the proper way and follow the approach that both @shivam7357 and I suggested. Instantiate it only once and use it wherever you need to collect the user input from the console.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about reading user input from the console? You could use the Scanner class in that case.

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = stdin.nextInt();
```

If you want to grab different input, no need to initialize a new scanner. You can use a different method from the scanner in that case, depending on the value you want.

```
System.out.println("Enter a double: ");
double myDouble = stdin.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter a string of characters: ");
String myString = stdin.next();
System.out.println("Enter a whole line of characters: ");
String myEntireLine = stdin.nextLine();
```

etc.